# How to match a particular string/regex split over different lines as seperate strings?

Tags: regex, scala, multiline

Here's a demonstration of the contents that are obtained from the code I've written. I'm reading a file lazily using Source.fromFile(filePath) and making use of .getLines() method to read each line as string and iterate over it to find if a certain word/pattern occurs in it.

Let's consider the pattern to be matched as ".read." . If the entire pattern is present on the same line, line.contains(".read.") works just fine. 
The problem arises if it is spread across subsequent lines in any of the following manners:

```
.
read.
```

or

```
.
read
.
```

or

```
.read
.
```

I can't even collect the entire contents of a file in a List[String] as the memory consumption would be too large so as to, concatenate the previous or next lines by making use of the index since its a bufferedSource iterator that's being used.

```
val bufferedSource = Source.fromFile("C:/code.scala")
val key = ".read."
var lineCounter = 0
for (bufferedline <- bufferedSource.getLines()) {
    lineCounter+=1
    val line = bufferedline.trim
    if (line.length() != 0) {
    if(line.contains(".read."))
        println("Found pattern at : "+lineCounter)
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to incorporate the changes, when the pattern is spread over multiple strings and not a single string seperated by newLine character. Any help would be appreciated on how to tackle this kind of problem.

Note - This was just a simple example if the pattern to be matched is spread across 3 lines, but there can be cases if a particular string say "spark.read.option" is to be found and its spread across 5 different lines.

Comment: What do you want to _do_ with the matches? Count them? Remove them from the file data? Is the pattern you're looking for always a concrete string or might it be a regex pattern? If the pattern can be split across a new-line character, might it also be split across other whitespace characters, or multiple new-line characters?

Comment: I want to find the line numbers where those particular matches occur in the file being read. It could be a regex pattern as well. The pattern will always be split across new line characters only, since I'm handling the whitespaces m by trimming every single line being rea and if there are multiple new lines, I have put the condition where line.length! =0. But yes, there can be multiple new lines and whitespaces after a newline too.

Comment: A regex pattern like `a.z` will match `abz` and `axz` but it won't match `ab\nz`. So a target string split across 5 lines of text won't be found unless the regex pattern accounts for possible newline chars anywhere inside and all 5 text lines have been read and buffered, which complicates your goal of not sucking everything into memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were attempting this I'd:

1. Give up on using `getLines()`. It complicates finding the target across multiple lines of text.
2. Give up on using a regex pattern as the target string. Finding a match that might, or might not, have multiple `\n` characters somewhere inside is asking a lot.

So instead, I'd look for a set target using a character-by-character search.

```
def findInFile(charItr :Iterator[Char], target :String) :Unit = {
  assert(target.nonEmpty)
  def consumeStr(subci   :Iterator[Char]
                ,str     :String
                ,lineNum :Int
                ) :Option[(Iterator[Char],Int)] =
    if      (str.isEmpty)    Some((subci,lineNum))
    else if (!subci.hasNext) None
    else subci.next() match {
      case '\n'               => consumeStr(subci, str, lineNum + 1)
      case c if c == str.head => consumeStr(subci, str.tail, lineNum)
      case _                  => None
    }

  def loop(ci :Iterator[Char], line :Int) :Unit = if (ci.hasNext) {
    ci.next() match {
      case '\n' => loop(ci, line+1)
      case c if c == target.head =>
        val (oldci,newci) = ci.duplicate
        consumeStr(newci, target.tail, line).fold(loop(oldci, line)){
          case (itr,ln) => println(s"target found: line $line")
                           loop(itr,ln)
        }
      case _ => loop(ci, line)
    }
  }

  loop(charItr, 1)
}
```

Here's the test file I used...

```
xxx
x
aa
aaaa
a.b
b.c
cccc
a
aa.bb.caaa.bb.cc.dd
xxx
```

...and the test target I searched for.

```
val src = io.Source.fromFile("so.txt")
findInFile(src, "aaa.bb.cc")
src.close()
//target found: line 4
//target found: line 9
```

---

OK, so I rejiggered `findInFile()` just a bit.

```
def findInFile(charItr :Iterator[Char], target :String) :List[(Int,String)] = {
  assert(target.nonEmpty)
  def consumeStr(subci   :Iterator[Char]
                ,str     :String
                ,lineNum :Int
                ) :Option[(Iterator[Char],Int)] =
    if      (str.isEmpty)    Some((subci,lineNum))
    else if (!subci.hasNext) None
    else subci.next() match {
      case '\n'               => consumeStr(subci, str, lineNum + 1)
      case c if c == str.head => consumeStr(subci, str.tail, lineNum)
      case _                  => None
    }

  def loop(ci :Iterator[Char], line :Int) :List[(Int,String)] =
    if (ci.hasNext) {
      ci.next() match {
        case '\n' => loop(ci, line+1)
        case c if c == target.head =>
          val (oldci,newci) = ci.duplicate
          consumeStr(newci, target.tail, line).fold(loop(oldci, line)){
            (line,target) :: (loop _).tupled(_)
          }
        case _ => loop(ci, line)
      }
    } else Nil

  loop(charItr, 1)
}
```

With this in place, and using the same test file as before, we can do the following:

```
val src1 = io.Source.fromFile("so.txt")  //open twice
val src2 = io.Source.fromFile("so.txt")

"a{2,3}.bb.c[ac]".r                                   //regex pattern
                 .findAllIn(src1.getLines().mkString) //all matches
                 .toSeq.distinct                      //remove duplicates
                 .foldLeft(src2.duplicate -> List.empty[(Int,String)]){
                   case (((srcA,srcB),lst),str) =>
                     (srcA.duplicate, lst ++ findInFile(srcB,str))
                 }._2.sorted
//res0: List[(Int, String)] = List((4,aa.bb.cc), (4,aaa.bb.cc), (8,aaa.bb.ca), (9,aa.bb.cc), (9,aaa.bb.cc))

src1.close()  //close up and go home
src2.close()
```

The idea is to first read the entire file into memory as a `String` without newline characters, then find all the regex matches and translate them into a list of all the unique matching strings. Then send each to `findInFile()`. Sort and return.

Not terribly efficient but it gets the job done.

Comment: I really like the approach you've taken to resolve the issue, but I presume this character by character iteration would only work on concrete strings that we're searching for and not for regex. What would you suggest if regex matching is also a mandatory requirement?

Comment: A) memory efficient (lazy reading) B) target may be split across multiple lines C) report line number where each found target starts D) use regex to search for targets. Choose any combination of 3.

Comment: If I had to compromise one thing, I would choose B, C, D.